# 404 error after scaffolding identity library of an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project

Tags: c#, identity, .net-6.0

I am using .NET 6. Every time I scaffold Identity, the application stops working.

My `Startup` class is like this:

```
using BulkBook.Data.Data;
using BulkBook.Data.Repository;
using BulkBook.Data.Repository.Common;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BulkDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BuldDbConnection")));
//builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
//    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BulkDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BulkDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

If I remove the `Identity` folder, then things start to work again.

`_ViewStart.cshtml` of identity contains the following code

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I did add areas in my controller but still it shows 404 error @Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used Area configuration to arrange the controllers. However, After adding Idenity library I don't why routing does not work. In order for this to work, I just decorated the controller classes with

```
[Area]
```

attribute and passed the name of the area. This solved to issue

Comment: I am looking at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-starter-and-completed-app - when I open the github code I cannot find the register page - any idea why?

Comment: you gave me hint. I also got 404 error, but then I saw that I use fallback policy. I removed it, and error gone:

Comment: builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

Answer (score 1):

Add area in your controller , it will do the trick

Comment: Hi can you tell me where do I have to add these attributes? As I am also stuck here

Answer (score 1):

I found that as I am using a number of areas I have been a bit more implicit. Not only do I declare the Area Attribte but also state the area.

[Area("Landing")]

This worked for me.

Comment: Hi can you tell me where do I have to add these attributes? As I am also stuck here